# Is it possible to divide the columns of a bootstrap-vue table into two groups by a vertical line?

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I would like to divide a bootstrap-vue table by a vertical line like this:

[image]

From the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table) it seems that it is possible only to have either borders between all columns, or no vertical borders at all, using either the `bordered` or `borderless` props of `<b-table>`.

Is this an inherent limitation of bootstrap-vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a custom class to apply to the column cells.

**regular CSS:**

```css
.b-table .my-left-border {
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
}
```

**or if using scoped styles**

```css
.b-table /deep/ .my-left-border {
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
}
```

Then do the following in your fields definition:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        'age',
        'first_name',
        {
          key: 'last_name',
          class: 'my-left-border'
        }
      ],
      // ...
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

```html
<b-table :fields="fields" ... ></b-table>
```

Another option is to use css selectors:

```css
.b-table /deep/ > thead > tr :nth-child(3),
.b-table /deep/ > tbody > tr :nth-child(3),
.b-table /deep/ > tfoot > tr :nth-child(3) {
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me